# Change string in list to floats

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list as follows:

```
pos = ['52.1,13.3','53.2,14.3',....,'55.3,16.4']
```

I want to change each string in the list to a float, such that I get the following:

```
pos = [52.1,13.3,53.2,14.3,....,55.3,16.4]
```

I am using the following loop:

```
b = []

for str in a:
    str = float(str)
    b.append(str)

print (b)
```

Which raises the following error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '52.1,13.3'
```

How do I change the strings into separate floats in a new list?

Comment: The required output is not consistent with the stated question. The output represents a list of integers - not floats

Comment: I edited the question such that it is consistent with the desired output. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I have voted to reopen the question because, after your edit, the original reason given for closure is irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split the strings at the comma and apply `float` to each of the entries. Then extend the list with those floating point values.

```
pos = ['52.1,13.3','53.2,14.3','55.3,16.4']

lst = []
for entry in pos:
    lst.extend(map(float, entry.split(',')))
print(lst)
```

This will give you `[52.1, 13.3, 53.2, 14.3, 55.3, 16.4]`.

---

If you're unfamiliar with `map` you should learn how to use it. But nevertheless here's a version with a loop approach:

```
lst = []
for entry in pos:
    for value in entry.split(','):
        lst.append(float(value))
print(lst)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will make use of the map version, did not know about this